# Alchemy Vision - creating custom classifier invalid API permissions

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I'm new to the Alchemy API and am able to make GET/POST requests using my API key, but for AlchemyVision I want to create my own classifiers. I followed the instructions linked below and keep getting an "invalid-api-key-permissions" error.

Here's how I'm posting; maybe I'm not getting something right with the syntax or need to remove the quotes? Would appreciate the help!

```
curl -X POST -F "husky_positive_examples=@Desktop/Husky.zip" 
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?api_key={MY_API_KEY}&version=2016-05-20"
```

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/tutorials.shtml#create_train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get your API key? If you provisioned an instance of [AlchemyAPI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alchemyapi/), then that key will not work for the call you referenced above.

To get access to image classifier creation, you need to provision an instance of the [Visual Recognition](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/visual-recognition/) service. Keys associated with that tile in Bluemix will work for the functionality you're after.

Additionally, once you get past the credentials issue, you'll need to include more bundles of examples for training. You can supply N positive training ZIPs, or you can simply provide 1 positive ZIP and 1 negative ZIP...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep this was the issue, thanks for the help. I got a new API key and was able to train w/ curl commands yesterday. But same issue today now while using the npm alchemy-api. I get an invalid permissions error when trying to classify an image (not train) in node (this npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/alchemy-api), but not when doing the command via curl with the same api key

Comment: Actually nvm, that's the same issue you mentioned. The alchemy-api npm module will only work for Alchemy Vision keys and not Visual Recognition.